RAM buildup after incrementally extracting data, preprocess and fe
I have one year worth of transaction data inside a mssql database and table. I've extracted the table day by day incrementally using pyodbc, then proceed to preprocess the extracted data, and then feature engineer them and then save the data to a csv file. As an example, the ranges of data inside the transaction data is 2022-01-01 until 2022-12-31. As the date goes up one by one, the process of table extraction takes longer and longer. During the extraction at date 2022-01-01, it will only take 10 seconds of extraction, but at 2022-01-29, it will take more than 3 hours of extraction. I don't know the exact reason as to why this happened, and how to solve it. my current solution is to stop the python program at 9pm, and then a task scheduler will start the python program again the next day from a checkpoint.
My main.py
def should_stop_execution():
    current_time = datetime.now().time()
    stop_time = datetime.strptime('21:00', '%H:%M').time()
    return current_time >= stop_time

# Checkpoint Functions
def save_checkpoint(last_processed_date, checkpoint_file='last_processed_date.txt'):
    with open(checkpoint_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(last_processed_date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

def load_checkpoint(checkpoint_file='last_processed_date.txt'):
    try:
        with open(checkpoint_file, 'r') as f:
            return datetime.strptime(f.read().strip(), '%Y%m%d')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

@log_to_file('AIS_log.log')
def main(server, database, table, start_date_str, end_date_str):
    cif_path = "./Data/raw/cif"
    acc_path = "./Data/raw/acc"
    utils.delete_folder_contents(cif_path)
    ais_read_save_data.cifextraction_eod(server, database, cif_table)
    utils.delete_folder_contents(acc_path)
    ais_read_save_data.accextraction_eod(server, database, acc_table)

    # Attempt to load from checkpoint
    checkpoint_start_date = load_checkpoint()
    if checkpoint_start_date:
        start_date = checkpoint_start_date
    else:
        start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date_str, format='%Y%m%d')
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date_str, format='%Y%m%d')
    
    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)
    all_time = []

    try:
        while start_date <= end_date:
            # Check if it's time to stop
            if should_stop_execution():
                print("Stopping execution at", datetime.now())
                break
            
            start = time.time()
            txn_path = "./data/raw/txn/"
            utils.delete_folder_contents(txn_path)
            txn = ais_read_save_data.bftextraction_initial(server, database, table, start_date) 
            
            # Check if it's time to stop
            if should_stop_execution():
                print("Stopping execution at", datetime.now())
                break
            
            
            print('read save complete')
            if txn is not None:
                del txn
                # Start processing - Assuming ais_eod_fe.main() is another process you want to call
                ais_eod_fe.main()

            end = time.time() - start
            print(end)
            all_time.append((str(start_date), end))

            # Save checkpoint after successful day processing
            save_checkpoint(start_date)
            
            # Move to next date
            start_date += timedelta(days=1)
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        df = pd.Series(all_time)
        df.to_csv('timelog.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(server, database, bftranhist, bftranhist_startdate, bftranhist_enddate)

My extraction.py
def bftextraction_initial(server, database, table, start_date, save_to_raw=True):
    parquet_path = f"{parent_dir}/data/raw/txn/"
    if not user:
        SQL_SERVER_ENGINE_URL = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')}"
    else:
        SQL_SERVER_ENGINE_URL = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};PWD={password};')}"
    engine = create_engine(SQL_SERVER_ENGINE_URL)

    columns_to_select = [
        'TRAN_NO',
        'SEQ_AUTO',
        'ACC_NO',
        'NO_CIF',
        'TRAN_PDATE',
        'TRAN_CODE1',
        'PROD_TYPE',
        'TRAN_LOC',
        'AMT_CR',
        'AMT_DR',
        'TRAN_TYPE',
        'AMT_CUR',
        'AMT_RATE',
        'SEND_NAME',
        'BENE_NAME',
        'TRAN_CODE2',
        'TRAN_CHAN',
        'SEND_BCTY',
        'BENE_BCTY',
        'UNIT_PRICE'
    ]

    columns_str = ', '.join(columns_to_select)
    
    end_date_int = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%Y%m%d')
    print(end_date_int)
    # REMOVE TOP 100000 AFTER TEST
    stmt = text(f"SELECT {columns_str} from {urllib.parse.quote_plus(table)} where TRAN_PDATE = {end_date_int}")

    try:
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            df = pd.read_sql(stmt, conn)
            if df is not None:
                print(df.shape)
                df = df.drop_duplicates(['TRAN_NO', 'SEQ_AUTO', 'ACC_NO', 'NO_CIF', 'TRAN_PDATE'])
                # print(df.shape)
                if save_to_raw:
                    dh.df_to_parquet(df, parquet_path)

            return df
        
    finally:
        engine.dispose()
        gc.collect()

If someone could help me, that would be great. Thank you so much

if you are buffering 000's of rows this may impact performance . Have you tried selecting initially from the date you say takes 3hrs ? how long does that take if its the first date. You may also want to look at using mysqldump to get the data out first and then 'feature engineer' .

Have you done any profiling to confirm that "RAM buildup" is really the problem? Good suggestion by @ticktalk re: switching up the date order. Depending on the type of transaction, 2022-01-01 may have significantly fewer observations because it is New Years Day.

Also, a couple of suggestions: (1) Use .read_sql_query() instead of .read_sql(). (2) Don't use urllib.parse.quote_plus() on the table name. If anything, use QUOTENAME. (3) Don't use dynamic SQL to insert the parameter value. Instead, use text(f"SELECT … where TRAN_PDATE = :tran_pdate") and then call .read_sql_query(…, params=dict(tran_pdate=end_date_int))

When I changed the dates to the dates that takes 3hrs, the extraction becomes faster again and it'll take like 10 seconds. And then it will incrementally takes longer and longer to extract the table. Also thank you @Gord Thompson for the suggestions. And also thank you ticktalk, I don't really get the reason as to why it takes longer and longer or is it a "RAM buildup" problem. I will try to look at mysqldump. Thanks again as I don't have a clue as to where to look for the problems.
